# Where to find source code and document for ext-tree.js 1.0.1

Tags: category-tree

I'm a bit surprised magento is using a super old ExtJS library whose version is 1.0.1, it's about 8 years old. In ExtJS website, there's no document or source code available for such old version. The JS library is compressed in magento installation. That makes development and debugging very difficult. Where can I found the related source code or document?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not really Magento specific.

Comment: I'm not sure why you said it's not magento specific. The ExtJs 1.0.1 is disappeared everywhere in the world except in magento platform. As a magento developer who wants to customize the category tree view. It's not avoidable to face the difficulties without source code and documentation. I really hope this channel is to help developers instead of blocking questions. I spend hours and finally find the source code which helped a lot:  https://github.com/nshbrown/toolbawks_extjs. I share it here hope to save others some time.

Comment: Then reform your question. You are asking about the documentation about extjs. Wouldn't it be easier of your stated your problem in the question?